# Reducer stuck due to dead host

Tags: hadoop

I noticed my reducer is stuck due to a dead host.  On the logs, it's showing a lot of retry messages.  Is it possible to tell job tracker to give up on the dead node and resume the work?  There were 323 mappers and only 1 reducer.  I am on hadoop-1.0.3.

```
2012-08-08 11:52:19,903 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: 192.168.1.23 Will be considered after: 65 seconds.
2012-08-08 11:53:19,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 Need another 63 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
2012-08-08 11:53:19,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (1 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-08-08 11:53:19,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Penalized(slow) Hosts: 
2012-08-08 11:53:19,905 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: 192.168.1.23 Will be considered after: 5 seconds.
2012-08-08 11:53:29,906 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 Scheduled 1 outputs (0 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-08-08 11:53:47,907 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 copy failed: attempt_201207191440_0203_m_000001_0 from 192.168.1.23
2012-08-08 11:53:47,907 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:173)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:240)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:321)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:338)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:876)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:801)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.getInputStream(ReduceTask.java:1618)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.setupSecureConnection(ReduceTask.java:1575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.getMapOutput(ReduceTask.java:1483)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.copyOutput(ReduceTask.java:1394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$ReduceCopier$MapOutputCopier.run(ReduceTask.java:1326)

2012-08-08 11:53:47,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Task attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0: Failed fetch #18 from attempt_201207191440_0203_m_000001_0
2012-08-08 11:53:47,907 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 adding host 192.168.1.23 to penalty box, next contact in 1124 seconds
2012-08-08 11:53:47,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0: Got 1 map-outputs from previous failures
2012-08-08 11:54:22,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 Need another 63 map output(s) where 0 is already in progress
2012-08-08 11:54:22,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: attempt_201207191440_0203_r_000000_0 Scheduled 0 outputs (1 slow hosts and0 dup hosts)
2012-08-08 11:54:22,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: Penalized(slow) Hosts: 
2012-08-08 11:54:22,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask: 192.168.1.23 Will be considered after: 1089 seconds.
```

I leave it alone and it retried for a while then give up on the dead host and rerun the mapper and succeeded.  It's caused by two ip addressed on the host and I intentionally turned off one ip which was the one hadoop use.

My question is whether there is a way to tell hadoop to give up the dead host without retrying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your log you can see that one of the tasktrackers which ran a map task can not be connected to. The tasktracker on which the reducer runs is trying to retrieve the map intermediate results through the HTTP protocol and it fails because the tasktracker having the results is dead.

The default behaviour for tasktracker failure is like this:

The jobtracker arranges for map tasks that were run and completed successfully on the failed tasktracker to be rerun if they belong to incomplete jobs, since their intermediate output residing on the failed tasktracker’s local filesystem may not be accessible to the reduce task. Any tasks in progress are also rescheduled.

The problem is that if a task(be it a map or a reduce) fails too many times (I think 4 times) it will not be rescheduled anymore and the job will fail. 
In your case, the map seems to complete successfully but the reducer is unable to connect to the mapper and retrieve the intermediate results. It tries 4 times and after that the job fails.

A failed task, cannot be completely ignored, as it is part of the job and unless all tasks comprised by the job succeed, the job itself doesn't succeed.

Try to find the link the reducer is trying to access and copy it in a browser to see the error you get.

You can also blacklist and completely exclude a node from the list of nodes Hadoop uses:

```
  In conf/mapred-site.xml

  <property>
     <name>mapred.hosts.exclude</name>
     <value>/full/path/of/host/exclude/file</value>
  </property>

  To reconfigure nodes.

  /bin/hadoop mradmin -refreshNodes
```

Comment: Thanks!  In my case, I leave it alone and it retried for a while then give up on the dead host and rerun the mapper and succeeded.  It's caused by two ip address on the host and I intentionally turned off one ip which was the one hadoop use.  My question is whether there is a way to tell hadoop to give up the dead host without retrying.

Comment: This is deeply unsatisfying if this is indeed the expected behavior of Hadoop. Hardware fails all the time. Hadoop is designed to be robust against hardware failure. When jobs fail due to limited hardware failures, this is a sign of a design flaw in Hadoop.